# How to add variables as part of expressions to a variable in r

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app, I created dynamic date range ui (`input$daterange[i]`) per selection of column(s) for date range input by users. And then I'd like to pass each `input$daterange[i]` value to a variable checking which rows in the corresponding column are within the user selected date range, I store the check results in `dt$range_checks[i]`. And then after checking all the `input$daterange[1:i]`, I'd combine the check results `dt$range_checks[1:i]` to find out which rows satisfy all check conditions, this value is to be stored in `dt$filtered_ind`. So I'll use this index to filter the dataset with rows meeting all date range requirements. However, I don't know how I'd do the last part right, how can I combine the dynamic checks to get the final index? Below please find my code:

Part 1 - generate daterange uis per date column(s) selected by user:

```
# generate daterange uis per selected input$datecols
  observeEvent({
    # when a new file uploaded
    input$file
    # when user change selection date column(s)
    input$datecols}, {

    dt$datecols = input$datecols
    dt$datecols_len = length(dt$datecols)

    # render daterange ui(s) per selected datecols
    output$daterangescontrol <- renderUI({

      # when input$datecols is NULL, no daterangecontrol ui
      if ( is.null(dt$datecols) ) { return(NULL) }

      # otherwise
      else {

        # whenever input$datecols change, start/end of daterange ui refresh to original state
        D = dt$data

        output = tagList()

        req(dt$datecols_len > 0)
        for (i in 1:dt$datecols_len) {
          output[[i]]= tagList()
          output[[i]][[1]] = tags$div(id = paste("dateranges_div", i, sep = "_"),
                                      dateRangeInput(paste0("daterange", i),
                                                     paste("Date range of", dt$datecols[[i]]),
                                                     start = min(D[[dt$datecols[[i]]]]),
                                                     end = max(D[[dt$datecols[[i]]]])
                                                    ))
        }

        # return output tagList() with ui elements
        output

      }

    })
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

Part 2: here goes the codes for assigning input$daterange data to filter corresponding columns:

```
  observe({

    # loop observeEvent on input$daterange1, input$daterange2... 
    lapply( 1:dt$datecols_len,

            FUN = function(i) {

              # don't call the following unless input$datecols is not of length 0
              req(dt$datecols_len > 0)

              # on change of input$daterange[i]
              observeEvent(input[[paste0("daterange", i)]], {

                # update reactive values to test whether this loop is working
                dt$range[[i]] = input[[paste0("daterange", i)]]

                req(dt$range[[i]])


                # filter dataset with the corresonding date column:
                D = dt$data[dt$cols]
                col = dt$datecols[[i]]
                dt$range_checks[i] = D[[col]] >=  dt$range[[i]][[1]] & D[[col]] <= dt$range[[i]][[2]]

              }) # end of observeEvent
            } 
    ) # end of lapply()

    lapply( dt$range_checks,
            FUN = function(x) {
              # How to write the code to get the following desired result????
              dt$filtered_ind = dt$range_checks[1] & dt$range_checks[2] ... dt$range_checks[i]
            }
          )

  })
```

Comment: Assuming that `dt$range_checks` is a list, how about binding into `data.frame` and checking with `all`? Like this: `apply(bind_cols(lapply(dt$range_checks, FUN=function(x){data.frame(x)})),1,all)`

Comment: Yes, this works! I initialize `dt$filtered_ind = 1`, and then multiple each range check (`dt$range_check[i]`) by `dt$filtered_ind` in a loop with the method you provided. Thanks!